# Any way of blocking spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

The past couple of days we've been getting lots of spam questions from [one particular user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/3631/mahi). I've been flagging them as spam, but are there any other tools at our disposal for dealing with this?

Example question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15812/watch-golf-the-barclays-championship-live-streaming

Answer (score 7):

We do keep an eye out for large amounts of spam network-wide, and can take certain actions to block it when necessary (IP bans, keyword bans, etc.)

That said, this particular form of spam is pretty difficult to block preemptively - it appears to be posted by actual humans, who can and do work around most of the checks implemented to stop spam bots. We're hard at work on better tooling, but for now the most effective option is to just flag it:

[image: flag as spam]

Enough of these flags, and the post will be removed automatically. If a moderator is around, they'll be notified and can destroy the user who posts the spam fairly easily. Finally, this feeds into some of our monitoring (and soon, blocking) tools, so it'll help us get better at stopping such nonsense network-wide.

Comment: Sorry, too many things going on at once here - site should be clean at the moment.

Comment: Looks clean now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Shog9!

Comment: Glad to hear you're working on better tools. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I just sent that user a warning. Any more spam, then suspension, then deletion. Seems like an account purely set up to spam the site, but there is a procedure for escalation.

Comment: Considering that I've seen probably 5 of those type of posts in the past 24 hours, I'd agree.

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193646/spam-deluge-over-at-webapps-and-pretty-much-all-over-se, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam - this is not isolated to SF, and I'm pretty sure you can nuke these on sight

Comment: +1 for nuke on sight.

Comment: Yeah, go ahead and just destroy these when you find them - there's a predefined reason listed under "destroy" in the user mod-menu for this sort of "user".

Comment: Cool - will nuke 'em on sight from low orbit...

Comment: I've just rejected an edit of anonymous user. Was spam too. And i still don't undertand why to allow anonymous edits at this site...